# Cannot import reportlab into Idle

Tags: python, python-import, reportlab

I've installed reportlab 3.5.68 using pip, and have verified that the installation works. If I open the Idle command line, I am able to successfully import reportlab without any issues.

However, when I open a script and then execute the script, I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFiundError: No module named 'reportlab'

In both cases, I'm using the exact same command: `import reportlab`

I've uninstalled and reinstalled reportlab, and have also forced reinstall.

I can't figure out why importing reportlab won't work when I try to incorporate it into my script, but it works at a command line level.

Comment: Is the version of python in IDLE and the command line the same?

Comment: Do you possibly have a Python 2 / Python 3 confusion?

Comment: I'm using python 3.9. It's the same version for IDLE and the command line

Comment: you may use the same `python` in IDLE  and command line but you may use different `pip` to install module. Check `pip -V` to see if it is `pip` for Python 3.9. Or try `pip3.9`. Or use `python -m pip install ...` to install in correct Python.